# Detect the Application which requests "services.exe" to start a service in Windows

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, win32-process, windows-kernel

As a part of my project, I get an event notification every time a Service is Started or Stopped using the WMI class [Win32_Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service) through an [EventSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/example--receiving-event-notifications-through-wmi-).
I want to detect the application which had requested "services.exe" to start a particular service.

Till now, I tried [Monitoring ALPC](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2017/02/12/monitoring-alpc-messages/) calls between any process and "services.exe" and got a Message_ID every time a process communicates (sends/receives) any information to/from "services.exe" using the [ALPC Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ETW/alpc). I would like to know what these messages are so that I can decode a StartService() or a StopService() procedure.

Is there any way to detect which application starts/stops a service?

Comment: There is no official way to detect which app is requesting a service be started/stopped.  Hooking ALPC is low level, and as the blogger stated, the messages are undocumented, so good luck decoding them.

Comment: You can use `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine/Ex/Ex2` from a device driver in kernel-mode (see the WDK documentation - it is straight forward after its been read). You won't have to involve topics like ALPC interface this way either. I saw on your profile you're working at FireEye - ask one of the kernel component engineers there, they'll know exactly what I am talking about and will be able to explain it to you.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR Thanks a lot for your valuable input. Was stuck in this for long as I didn’t know whether it was possible. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, in my opinion, would be from kernel-mode using the `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine/Ex/Ex2` kernel-mode callback.

---

If you're going to be using `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`, you will receive less information than if you were using the Extended version of the kernel-mode callback (the Ex one). However, you can still query information such as the image file path of the parent process (or the one being created) by using `PsLookupProcessByProcessId` to get a pointer to the `_EPROCESS` structure and then relying on `SeLocateProcessImageName` (undocumented, however it is accessible in WDK by default).

The `SeLocateProcessImageName` routine will rely internally on that `_EPROCESS` structure, since information like the path of the process image on-disk is all tracked by the Windows kernel there.

---

If you're going to be using the Ex version of the kernel-mode callback, then you eliminate the need to do what is mentioned above. The Ex version of the routine is more recent than the non-Ex version.

The routine prototype for the callback routine will be:

```
VOID
CreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(
    PEPROCESS Process,
    HANDLE ProcessId,
    PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo
)
```

As seen above, you get a pointer to the `_PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO` structure. You can then access the `ImageFileName` and `CommandLine` fields to filter for `services.exe` (make sure you filter properly to not catch it for a rogue copy - so ensure full path indicates its the real one) and gain more insight into why it was being invoked (if such information is exposed via the command-line... I cannot remember - nonetheless, you can still detect its creation and be aware of who spawned it).

To determine the parent who was responsible for the process creation operation of `services.exe` (e.g. if it relied on the Service Manager which in turn resulted in the spawning of it), you can rely on the `ParentProcessId` field (under the `_PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO` structure as well). The `SeLocateProcessImageName` trick will work perfectly here.

---

`SeLocateProcessImageName` is undocumented so here is the routine prototype:

```
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
SeLocateProcessImageName(
    PEPROCESS Process,
    PUNICODE_STRING *ImageName
);
```

At-least with the latest Windows 10 WDK, it's already available by default. If you wanted to though, you can use a dynamic import with `MmGetSystemRoutineAddress`.

---

Resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutineex

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutineex2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-pslookupprocessbyprocessid

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_ps_create_notify_info